# Dictate note to Cortana with UWP app

Tags: uwp, cortana

I want to set up an app that integrates with Cortana exactly like OneNote does. Ie you tell Cortana "Take note", Cortana replies "What's your note", listens and parses the speech and then presents an Cortana interface with  a link to the note, all using Cortana's own  UI.

I've read a lot of the samples and tutorials, using a background service etc and some of these things are not hard, but most samples are oriented against structured voice commands and phrase lists. I can't seem to figure out how to do the "dictation" part in the Cortana UI. I could launch my app in the foreground and do it there but that would feel less seamless.

Is there some kind of special integration with OneNote or can you accomplish the same thing with a third-party app?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following Code in your VoiceCommand.xml

```
<Command Name="naturalLanguage">
      <Example> listen to  what I have to say </Example>
      <ListenFor> listen {naturalLanguage} </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> You sad {naturalLanguage} </Feedback>
      <Navigate Target="VoiceCommandService"/>
</Command>
<PhraseTopic Label="naturalLanguage" Scenario="Natural Language">
      <Subject> Natural Language </Subject>
</PhraseTopic>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That seems slightly different though in that it needs to take the whole phrase in one utterance, When  you say "take note" it replies "sure, what's on your mind", and then you proceed to take the note

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that that's what you wanted. I have not seen anything in the API that would allow for that. Maybe you could use the OneNote API to get the Note from there?